# How to cut the last N chars of a TStringStream?

Tags: delphi, stringstream, delphi-xe7

I'm writing some strings into a `TStringStream` dividing them by using a string separator.

```
var
  Stream : TStringStream;
  i : integer;
  Separator : string;
begin
  Separator := '|';
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    i := 0;
    while(i < 5) do
    begin
      Stream.WriteString(IntToStr(i) + ' test' + Separator);
      Inc(i);
    end;

    Stream.Size := Stream.Size - Length(Separator) * SizeOf(Char);

    Stream.SaveToFile('.\test.txt');
  finally
    Stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

At the end of the loop, I want to remove the last separator:

```
Stream.Size := Stream.Size - Length(Separator) * SizeOf(Char);
```

It produces the following `test.txt` output file:

```
0 test|1 test|2 test|3 test|4 tes
```

`SizeOf(Char)` in *Delphi XE7* is 2, but it seems that `TStringString` is using one byte for each char. I don't think I can assume that it's always 1 byte, so how can I safely cut the last N characters from the stream?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the last separator instead of not adding it in the first place?

Comment: @Ancaron: Because in very big loops, checking inside the loop would be heavier than cutting at the end of the loop.

Comment: _Because in very big loops, checking inside the loop would be heavier than cutting at the end of the loop_ So add first item before the loop and then add `Separator+Item` in the loop, no need for any extra condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by using the [`TEncoding.GetByteCount`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TEncoding_GetByteCount@PChar@Integer.html) method.

> Returns the number of bytes generated by encoding Chars. Note that the
>   number of bytes in a string is not necessarily exactly proportional to
>   the number of characters in a given character array or string.
>
> The Chars parameter can be a character array or a character pointer
>   containing the bytes to be counted.
>
> The S parameter refers to a UnicodeString from which the Byte count
>   will be extracted.
>
> The CharCount parameter specifies the number of characters to encode.
>
> The CharIndex parameter indicates the index within the Chars array
>   where counting should begin.
>
> The CharCount parameter indicates the number of characters that should
>   be included when counting the bytes.
>
> The Return Value is the number of bytes in the passed Chars or S
>   parameter.

The last separator can be removed from the stringstream as follows:

```
Stream.Size := Stream.Size - Stream.Encoding.GetByteCount(Separator);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. `TStringStream` is a `TMemoryStream` descendant in D2009+. Internally, it stores *encoded bytes*, not *characters*. So the `Size` has to be adjusted in terms of those encoded bytes, which is why using `Length(Separator) * SizeOf(Char)` can truncate too many bytes when using an 8bit encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The Size property of a TStringStream is automatically (and unavoidably) updated when data is written to it.  So surely the thing to do is to write the separator separately and record the size of the stream immediately **before** you do it?  Then you can easily truncate the stream at that point when you want to discard the final separator.

```
var
  PrvSize : Int64;;

[...]
  PrvSize := Stream.Size
  Stream.WriteString(Separator);
[...]
  Stream.Size := PrvSize;
```